# Delete anything other than pattern

Tags: search, vim

Let's say this is my text:

**this is my text this

is my text this is my text

my text is this**

I would like to highlight all text except pattern and delete the highlighted text.
p.e. `text`: this must be the result.

**text

texttext

text**

I've found the code how to select all text except pattern:
`\%(\%(.{-}\)\@!text\zs\)*`

however I don't know how to delete all highlighted text.
This doesn't work:
`:%s/\%(\%(.{-}\)\@!bell\zs\)*//`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Related: [How to delete part of a line that does not match a pattern?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3213/467) at Vi SE

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
:%s/\(^\|\(text\)\@<=\).\{-}\($\|text\)\@=//g
```

Explanation:

```
\(^\|\(text\)\@<=\)     # means start of line, or some point preceded by “text”
.\{-}                   # as few characters as possible
\($\|text\)\@=          # without globbing characters, checking that we reached either end of line or occurrence of “text”.
```

Another way to do it:

- Create a function that count matches of a pattern in a string (see `:help match()` to help you design that)
- Use: `:%s/.*/\=repeat('text', matchcount('text', submatch(0)))`

Comment: I tried to put your code `:%s/\(^\|\(text\)\@<=\).\{-}\($\|text\)\@=//g` in menu.vim, do you know why this does work on the commandline but not in menu.vim (or vimrc). Do I have to use double backslashes or something like that?

Comment: @Remonn: Those files are read before your file is loaded. Try to setup an autocmd or to make a command.

Comment: I created this command in menu.vim: `nnoremenu <silent> 96.061.11 &Matches.Delete\ all\ but\ Matches\    :%s/\(^\|\(<C-r>/\)\@<=\).\{-}\($\|<C-r>/\)\@=//g<CR>` this gives the error nothing found, same error when I change <C-r>/ in "text"

Comment: You must escape the pipes (`\|` => `\\|`).

Comment: Benoit, something doesn't work in your function. It removes the last character in p.e when I search all email addresses: `\([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]\+\.[a-zA-Z]\{2,4}\)`

Comment: @Benoit can you explain more about `\@<=` and `\@=`? Thanks!

Comment: @congliu, type `:help /\@<=` and `:help /\@=` or more generally `:help pattern` and read the whole section, this is better than anything I could tell you. In short, those two things are lookbehind and lookahead positive assertions, and if you replace `=` with `!` they become negative.

Comment: Using very magic and breaking the command into search and substitution, makes easier to understand - Search  `/\v(^|(text)@<=).{-}($|text)@=`
 Substituition   `:%s,,\1,g`

Answer (score 10):

Forgive me, because I'm not a vim expert, but wouldn't prepending the search with `v` find the inverse so that you could do something like this?

```
:v/pattern/d
```

Comment: this deletes the whole line without the highlighting and keeps the whole line with highlighting not just the highlighted text.

Comment: That's true.  So while this answer doesn't really solve the original question, I've found the :v command to be very, very useful.

Answer (score 5):

I've implemented Benoit's clever regular expression as a custom `:DeleteExcept` command in my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602). It offers other related commands like `:SubstituteExcept` or `:SubstituteInSearch`, too.

OP's example would be

```
:%DeleteExcept /text/
```

Comparing that with @Benoit's explicit command (`:%s/\(^\|\(text\)\@<=\).\{-}\($\|text\)\@=//g`), it's a lot simpler.

Comment: To the downvoter: If you have constructive feedback, please post it here, or contact me directly.

Comment: Please add an example of usage of this command. Currently, there is no way to understand how it works.

Comment: @RohanGhige Thanks for the feedback; I've added an example. For me, the syntax appears to be straightforward, but you're right, one cannot expect that from the reader, and not everybody will click through to the plugin's page.