# How can I remove all the text between matches on a line?

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

I have this problem:

Input text:

```
this is my text text text and more text
this is my text myspace this is my text
this space is my text space this is my
this is my text this is my text
this space is my text space space myspace
```

Let say I want to search for "space"
I would like to have this as output:

```
this is my text text text and more text
space
space space
this is my text this is my text
space space space space
```

Matches on the same line have to be separated with a space.
Line without matches must remain as it is.

Same for all other search items.

I'm trying to realize this, this afternoon but without success.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VIM: delete anything other than pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249172/vim-delete-anything-other-than-pattern)

Comment: This is a tricky problem; does it have to be done in vim?  Would be much easier to accomplish with awk.

Comment: @Ingo, not quit the same, The solution proposed in the other question does remove the text in the line with non matches. The solution proposed in the other question does not have a space between the matches.

Comment: The question indicated by Ingo in the text does not have an answer for me, so please respect this question.

Comment: @Remonn You only need to adapt the solution in the other answer to keep the whitespace (that's `\s`), and then deal with any leading / trailing leftover whitespace. That's a trivial modification, and you could have at least referenced your previous question and tell where you failed. I don't understand why you can't get there on your own, instead spamming this site with you quirky questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

`:g/space/s/\(.*space\).*$/\1/|s/.\{-}space/ space/g|s/^ //`

### Explanation:

This is tricky, but it can be done.  It can't be done with a single regular expression, though.

The first thing we do is get rid of anything after the last match (we actually exploit the fact that regular expressions are greedy by default here):

```
s/\(.*space\).*$/\1/
```

Then we remove anything between all the internal matches (notice we use the lazy version of `*` here, `\{-}`):

```
s/.\{-}space/ space/g
```

The previous step will leave an initial space in the result, so we get rid of that:

```
s/^ //
```

Fortunately, in vim, we can chain replacements together with the `|` character.  So, putting it all together:

```
:g/space/s/\(.*space\).*$/\1/|s/.\{-}space/ space/g|s/^ //
```

Comment: Thank you Ethan, Very nice solution. I hope it will work also with other searches like regex searches. Will check it a bit more.

Comment: p.e. searching for `\d,\d\+\|\d\+` gives problems in your code, but I changed it a bit and now it works. Tnx again. Tnx also to Kent. I learned about ^G but found your code easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

is this tricky line ok for you?

```
:g/space/s/space/^G/g|s/[^^G]//g|s/^G/space /g
```

the `^G` above you need press `Ctrl-V Ctrl-G`

the output of above command is *same* as your example except for the ending whitespace after pattern (space in this case). but it is easy to be fixed, e.g. chain another `s/ $//` after the `:g` line.

Comment: Cool! The `^G` is a nice touch to make it extra cryptic but of course any byte sequence that doesn't occur in lines will do. Nice one.

Comment: Thank you Kent, I will check it a bit more to see if it works with other searches as well (p.e. searches with regex code).

Comment: @Remonn it won't work for dynamic regex. e.g. `/r.d/` when I restore `^G` back to keyword, I don't know it is `red or rod or rid...`

Answer (score 0):

Kent's solution uses a nice trick that makes it work only for fixed strings, but it's clean and short. Ethan Brown's answer is more general, but also adds complexity with its three steps. I think the best solution can be developed based on [the accepted answer in this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249291/813602).

Contrary to what Ethan Brown assumes, this can indeed be done with a *single regular expression substitution*. Here it is, in all its ugliness:

```
:g/space/s/\%(^\|\%(space \)*space\%( \%(.*space\)\@=\)\?\)\zs\%(\%(space \)*space\%( \%(.*space\)\@=\)\?\)\@!.\{-1,}\ze\%(\%(space \)*space\%( \%(.*space\)\@=\)\?\|$\)//g
```

It becomes somewhat more readable when you use the `:DeleteExcept` command from my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602):

```
:g/space/DeleteExcept/\%(space \)*space\%( \%(.*space\)\@=\)\?/
```

#### Explanation

This deletes everything except

- potentially multiple sequential occurrences `\%(space \)*`
- of the word `space`
- including the trailing whitespace when it's not the last match in the line, i.e. there's a following match `\%(.*space\)\@=` so that the whitespace is not swallowed
- or excluding (i.e. deleting) it `\?` after the last match in the line.

### More practical alternative

Though it's a nice challenge to come up with the above solution, in practice, I would also favor a two-step approach, just because it's way simpler:

```
:g/space/DeleteExcept/space\%( \|$\)/
```

This leaves behind trailing whitespace that can be pruned with

```
:%s/ $//
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Isn't it possible to resolve my question also using submatch(0)?