# Delete anything other than pattern (version 2)

Tags: vim, pattern-matching

Hi:  I have a follow up question to one that has already been asked.  The earlier one has been dealt with in link below

[Delete anything other than pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249172/delete-anything-other-than-pattern)

In that post question was delete everything other than pattern.  In the provided sample the asker wanted to delete everything other than the word "text".  So for following input

```
this is my text this
is my text this is my text
my text is this
```

Output should be

```
text
texttext
text
```

The provided solution was very elegant and seems to have worked seamlessly

```
:%s/\(^\|\(text\)\@<=\).\{-}\($\|text\)\@=//g
```

Only problem is that assume now that sought after patterns is not a constant "text" but instead a true pattern which is variable.

For example consider following modified input

```
this is my text1 this
is my text2 this is my text34
my text100 is this
```

Now I want to delete all except any mention of "text" followed by a bunch of integers.  The outcome in the case should be

```
text1
text2text34
text100
```

That is only `text\d\+` has been kept.  I tried the above recipe with the required modifications of pattern including digits at the end but unfortunately it does not seem to be working.  In particular I tried

```
:%s/\(^\|\(text\d\+\)\@<=\).\{-}\($\|text\d\+\)\@=//g
```

but outcome did not come out quite right!!

```
text1
text2text3
text1
```

Notice that text34 has been reduced to text3 and text100 to text1.  Is there a way around this?

P.S -- the other suggested solution in same post of setreg -- I suspect, though I have not tired it -- should work.  But it does require a few interim steps and my preference -- if possible -- is a one liner using `\@=, \@<=, \zs` ... and friends.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking closer at this I think the weak point was using `.\{-}` as that does include part of the pattern (that is trailing digits).  If I instead use `[^0-9]\{-}`, that is exclude digits then it's looking like following remedy works!!

```
:%s/\(^\|\(text\d\+\)\@<=\)[^0-9]\{-}\($\|text\d\+\)\@=//g
```

In particular now I get

```
text1
text2text34
text100
```

which is what I am after.

Any feedback appreciated; any variant solution would also be appreciated.

Thanks